# How to hide page header in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

I have created a crystal report to show the English Exam marks for students and walk-ins for my project. The information is shown in two sub reports(1 for students and other for walk-ins). There is no information to show on the page header or the report footer while on page footer i display the page number, print date and print time. Now I wanted to hide/suppress the page header(since it contains no information). I tried suppress blank sections and suppress(No-Drill Down). But both these does not do the desired. Now the Page Number 1 has no information and is blank. If we take a print out, it is a waste of 1st page. Please provide me some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If page header has no information then instead of using `supress blank section` directly supress the page header by right click on page header

Answer (score 0):

dear if your header have text then use the formula field for the header
go to the toolbar and in the formula field create new formula like

```
if(condition) then
   your header text
else
""
```

also take look to the following link [Book](http://books.google.ae/books?id=btX1y7Izd7QC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=crystal%20reports%20how%20to%20suppress%20group%20header%20based%20on%20formula&source=bl&ots=lqXKu2KD0c&sig=PBPDylKZexbO-yQvvEpDSaracsg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=srEAU-mzFMye7Aanq4BY&ved=0CGwQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=crystal%20reports%20how%20to%20suppress%20group%20header%20based%20on%20formula&f=false)
and if you want to suppress you header the also make it suppress by formula
right click on the header section and click on section expert and in the popup window write formal for the suppress same as above 
:D